# Area generator from 2 points in d3.js like polygonHull

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Because d3.polygonHull must have at least 3 points, I need to make something similar but only with 2 points like in image [d3 shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF6f6.png)

Comment: Can you add code and things you've tried before people downvote your question?

Comment: I just found solution here: [smooth hull](http://bl.ocks.org/hollasch/9d3c098022f5524220bd84aae7623478)